# VLAN 'Bridging' for Core on Multiple Networks

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, bridge

I think I have a very unique use-case that I need help with since I am not a network engineer. Here's the layout. I help operate a gaming floor network for a Casino. The thing that I noticed right away is that we have been operating under the assumption is that the gaming authority didn't allow virtual separation, which after investigating other properties in the state, is not true. So I have 8+or- different vendor networks that I would like to centralize under a single mdf core rack and establish lags and redundancies. We operate a huge amount of switches because every IDF has unique vendor network switches.

Currently I would need to organize all of these vendors and their SE and see if they can modify their racks VLAN output, and with that in mind, some of these have been on property for awhile so modifying it for us may lead us down a can of worms since the initial rack builders are probably long gone.

I believe all of the vendors come out untagged. As we can throw in dummy switches and operate just fine. However these vendors have used some of the same VLANs like vlan 2 and vlan 200. I was hoping that I could accept all the different vendor untagged vlans into the mdf core and then use the mdf core to bridge or establish different vlan #s as to bypass a vendor circus and have a clean organized vlan tree. Is it possible to essentially use my core switch to operate a different vlan than what the vendor racks switch is outputting if it is untagged?

Sorry for the word salad

Comment: VLANs terminate at a layer-3 device, so there is no problem with the same VLAN numbers in different LANs as long as they are separated by a layer-3 device, such as a router or layer-3 switch.

Comment: So @RonMaupin, if I were to bring in the different vendors to a L3 switch, I can create a different VLAN out to my MDF Core L2 switch network and keep all these vendors logically separated?

Comment: The goal with a layer-3 device is to terminate the layer-2 separation, and now you have traffic that has different layer-3(network) addresses. you really want to end the layer-2 as close to the source as possible.